# How to properly list time zones within a form?

Tags: forms, timezone, timezone-offset

I am creating a form (using Typeform, but doesn't really matter) in which I need to understand the time zone of my customers. So far I have left this as an open questions, but I would like to provide an extensive list, to ensure consistency on my database.

I could provide a list of time zones abbreviation (such as [this](https://www.timeanddate.com/time/zones/) one), but then I'd have the problem of daylight saving times. That is, let's say a customer is in the UK, they will see both "Greenwich Mean Time" and "British Summer Time" on the list, and would be answering differently depending on the time of the year.

How can a produce a meaningful non-redundant plaintext list of timezones?